# How to fit a model that allows three different odds ratio?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, model, odds-ratio

[image]

From this example, I'm trying to fit a model with three different odds ratio by combining centers(1,2,4,7),(3,5,6) and 8. Would it be possible to fit the model with three different odds ratio?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! The answer depends on how you are making the choice of those particular combinations of centers. If the choice is based on some underlying characteristic (e.g., country) without regard to the already known results, that's probably OK. If you are choosing those combinations based on the already observed odds ratios (e.g., intermediate, high, and low odds ratios), then it's probably not OK. Please edit your question to say more about the question you are trying to answer and the basis for your grouping the centers the way that you propose.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! If the centers were grouped by regions, what kind of a model do you think will be able to fit three different odds ratio?

Answer (score 1):

Simple tests like those on the contingency tables shown in the question can be extended to regression models that take additional information into account. In this situation you are modeling odds and odds ratios, so the natural extension is to a [logistic regression model](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/).

Logistic regression models the log-odds of a binary outcome (Success/Failure here) as a function of a set of predictors. Exponentiating a log-odds value gives the odds. Exponentiating a difference of log-odds between two conditions, say `Drug` versus `Control`, gives the odds ratio.

Logistic regression software typically can accept a two-column matrix of successes and failures as the outcome for each data row. Each data row would also be annotated by the `Treatment` received, the `Center`, and the `Group` to which the `Center` is assigned. To allow for a different `Treatment` effect for each `Group` you would use `Treatment`, `Group`, and their interaction as predictors. The results can then be interpreted in terms of the odds ratio associated with `Treatment` for each `Group`, giving you the desired 3 odds ratios.

Your model should take each individual `Center` into account, not just the `Group` assignments. That's often done by a [mixed effects logistic regression model](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/mixed-effects-logistic-regression/), although that might not work well with so few Centers in each `Group`. Alternatively, you could model by `Center` instead of by `Group` at first, then combine results by `Group` with post-modeling software tools like those provided by the R [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans).

As noted in comments, this grouping only is valid if  there was a reason known *before you saw the results* to combine the different centers into 3 groups, for example their geographic locations. If the proposed grouping in the question is based on the already known odds ratios (e.g., these seem to be intermediate, high, and low odds-ratio groups) the results would not be valid, as the assumptions of independence that underlie the statistical tests wouldn't hold.